# Algolia saveObject not called inside Lambda function using Serverless framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, algolia

I'm using a Lambda function to index records into Algolia. I'm able to get the data via the `event` object. I'am running into a problem where the `saveObject` function of Algolia doesn't seem to call or it returns before finishing what it is doing. Bit hard to debug as well since I have to look at cloudwatch every time. I threw some `console.log`s here and there to see if the flow is correct. I'm kind of stuck here. Any help is much appreciated.

**search.js**

```js
'use strict';

const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

const ALGOLIA_APP = 'appid';
const ALGOLIA_KEY = 'algoliakey';
const INDEX = 'indexname';

const connectToIndex = (appId,apiKey,index) => {
  const client = algoliasearch(appId,apiKey);
  return client.initIndex(index);
};

const updateIndex = async (record) => {
  console.log('updating/replacing') //logs in cloudwatch
  const index = connectToIndex(ALGOLIA_APP,ALGOLIA_KEY,INDEX);
  console.log(record,index); //logs the record object and index object in cloudwatch
  index.saveObject(record)
  .then(()=>{
    console.log('updated/replaced')  //doesn't log in cloudwatch + not indexed in algolia
    return;
  }
  ).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
    return;
  });
}

module.exports.algoliaIndexer = async (event, cb) => {
    try {
      const body = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
      const record = {...restructuring body}; //record to index
      if (body.detail.operationType === 'update' || body.detail.operationType === 'replace'){
        updateIndex(record);
        console.log('done1') //logs in cloudwatch
      }
      console.log('done2') //logs in cloudwatch
      cb(null, responseObj('success', 200));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      cb(null, responseObj(e.message, 500));
    }
  };
```

**handler.js** contains the lambda function

```js
'use strict';

const search = require('./lib/search');

let algoliaIndexer = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  search.algoliaIndexer(event, callback);
};

module.exports = {
  algoliaIndexer : algoliaIndexer 
}
```

**EDIT**
I tried with `await updateIndex(record)` as well with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a `try` `catch` block in the `updateIndex` function combined with [@Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190823/jens)'s answer solved the issue for me.

**search.js**

```js
const updateIndex = async (record) => {
  const index = connectToIndex(ALGOLIA_APP,ALGOLIA_KEY,INDEX);
  try{
    await index.saveObject(record);
  }
  catch(e){
    console.error(e);
  }
}

module.exports.algoliaIndexer = async (event, cb) => {
    try {
      const body = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
      const record = {...restructuring body}; //record to index
      if (body.detail.operationType === 'update' || body.detail.operationType === 'replace'){
        await updateIndex(record);
      }
      cb(null, responseObj('success', 200));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      cb(null, responseObj(e.message, 500));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'am running into a problem where the saveObject function of Algolia doesn't seem to call or it returns before finishing what it is doing.

That's the issue. You are not *waiting* for the `saveObject` function to finish (return the result). To do this you need to `await` for your `async` functions return (the concept is called [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)).

So, try changing this line:

```
updateIndex(record);
```

to

```
await updateIndex(record);
```

This should fix the issue.

Furthermore, you are using an `async` handler with a callback. That might also break something. You either use an `async` handler *OR* a callback, not both.

Try the following handler signature:

```js
module.exports.algoliaIndexer = async (event) {
  ... your code ...
}
```

Relevant documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

Comment: hi @Jens thanks for the reply. I changed to await, redeployed and tested. still the same behaviour :(

Comment: @cmgchess I have update my answer, because I found another issue.